# What is the correct way to free memory in C#

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I have a timer in C# which executes some code inside it's method. Inside the code I'm using several temporary objects.

1. If I have something like `Foo o = new Foo();` inside the method, does that mean that each time the timer ticks, I'm creating a new object and a new reference to that object?
2. If I have `string foo = null` and then I just put something temporal in foo, is it the same as above?
3. Does the garbage collector ever delete the object and the reference or objects are continually created and stay in memory?
4. If I just declare `Foo o;` and not point it to any instance, isn't that disposed when the method ends?
5. If I want to ensure that everything is deleted, what is the best way of doing it:

   - with the using statement inside the method
   - by calling dispose method at the end
   - by putting `Foo o;` outside the timer's method and just make the assignment `o = new Foo()` inside, so then the pointer to the object is deleted after the method ends, the garbage collector will delete the object.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> 1.If I have something like Foo o = new Foo(); inside the method, does that
>   mean that each time the timer ticks,
>   I'm creating a new object and a new
>   reference to that object?

Yes.

> 2.If I have string foo = null and then I just put something temporal in foo,
>   is it the same as above?

If you are asking if the behavior is the same then yes.

> 3.Does the garbage collector ever delete the object and the reference or
>   objects are continually created and
>   stay in memory?

The memory used by those objects is most certainly collected after the references are deemed to be unused.

> 4.If I just declare Foo o; and not point it to any instance, isn't that
>   disposed when the method ends?

No, since no object was created then there is no object to collect (dispose is not the right word).

> 5.If I want to ensure that everything is deleted, what is the best way of
>   doing it

If the object's class implements `IDisposable` then you certainly want to greedily call `Dispose` as soon as possible. The `using` keyword makes this easier because it calls `Dispose` automatically in an exception-safe way.

Other than that there really is nothing else you need to do except to stop using the object. If the reference is a local variable then when it goes out of scope it will be eligible for collection.<sup>1</sup> If it is a class level variable then you may need to assign `null` to it to make it eligible before the containing class is eligible.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is technically incorrect (or at least a little misleading). An object can be eligible for collection long before it goes out of scope. The CLR is optimized to collect memory when it detects that a reference is no longer used. In extreme cases the CLR can collect an object even while one of its methods is still executing!

**Update:**

Here is an example that demonstrates that the GC will collect objects even though they may still be in-scope. You have to compile a Release build and run this outside of the debugger.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before allocation");
    var bo = new BigObject();
    Console.WriteLine("After allocation");
    bo.SomeMethod();
    Console.ReadLine();
    // The object is technically in-scope here which means it must still be rooted.
}

private class BigObject
{
    private byte[] LotsOfMemory = new byte[Int32.MaxValue / 4];

    public BigObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BigObject()");
    }

    ~BigObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~BigObject()");
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin SomeMethod");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("End SomeMethod");
    }
}
```

On my machine the finalizer is run while `SomeMethod` is still executing!

Comment: how exactly would you end up inside of a object's method without that object having a rooted reference?

Comment: @Yaur: Good question: Consider an instance method which uses no other instance members (variables or methods). That means the object reference only needs to be extract to pass the `this` reference. After that the object is technically eligible as long as the CLR can detect that it is not used later on even though it may still be rooted.

Comment: @Brian Gideon I see your point but I'm skeptical since the CLR uses mark-and-sweep to determine GC eligibility that this would ever happen or that the object is even technically "eligible" of garbage collection. But this is, in any case, an interesting enough case to do some testing.

Comment: @Yaur: It is pretty easy to demonstrate that an object can be collected while it is still rooted. Create a really big object in the `Main` method via a simple constructor call and assign it to a local reference. Then start allocating a lot more memory to trigger a GC, but make sure you do not use that reference ever again in the `Main` method. You may need to define a destructor on the object so that you can verify that the finalizer was called *before the reference goes out of scope*. Make sure you run it with a Release build outside of the debugger.

Comment: @Yaur: I posted an example that demonstrates what I was talking about. Note, I suspect this behavior may be highly dependent on which CLR version is being tested. Earlier versions may not have this optimization. It is a fairly interesting demonstration of just how aggressive the GC can be.

Comment: @Brian Gideon your example is somewhat flawed because bo can be optimized away, but you are correct. I added some code here that indisputably shows that unreachable objects that are still rooted (and have a method executing) can indeed be collected.

Comment: @Yaur: Another fun excerise would be to see if you can get `bo` to get collected for *before* `Begin SomeMethod` is printed. I suspect this may be possible if memory pressure (or call to `GC.Collect`) were occurring on anothr thread. But, an even more fun test would be to see if we can somehow get `bo` collected *before* `SomeMethod` even appears on the stack. I have some ideas on how this might be accomplished, but it would involve some IL trickery and I entirely doubt if it is even possible.

Comment: @Yaur: Oh, and yeah, my example was wrong. I left out the call to `bo.SomeMethod`. That is fixed now.

Comment: @Yaur: Anyway, one idea I have is to compile the example and then disassemble via ILDASM. There should be a `callvirt` instruction that executes `SomeMethod`. I wonder what would happen if that were changed to a `call` instruction instead. The `call` instruction does not extract the `this` reference when making method calls and is still legal IL even when using it on instance methods. I will try this Monday when I get back work. CLR version may have an impact here since 4.0 handles the `call` instruction differently.

Answer (score 18):

The .NET garbage collector takes care of all this for you.

It is able to determine when objects are no longer referenced and will (eventually) free the memory that had been allocated to them.

Comment: Are you sure that even the objects that are created inside the timer are deleted? Because I encountered an issue where my application in 10 minutes was 700mb and I'm guessing that something goes wrong with the objects that should be deleted in the timer.

Comment: Unless you're doing something to hold on to those references created within the scope of the timer's "tick" method, they will be released *at some time* after the method exits. This is up to when the garbage collector runs and detects that nothing is still pointing to those objects. If your timer ticks on a fast enough cycle I can see how it would be possible to consume a huge amount of memory.

Comment: It takes care of all this... except when it doesn't.  Not worrying about memory management is a great way to get out of control heap growth.

Answer (score 9):

Objects are eligable for garbage collection once they <strike>go out of scope</strike> become unreachable (thanks ben!). The memory won't be freed unless the garbage collector believes you are running out of memory.

For managed resources, the garbage collector will know when this is, and you don't need to do anything.

For unmanaged resources (such as connections to databases or opened files) the garbage collector has no way of knowing how much memory they are consuming, and that is why you need to free them manually (using dispose, or much better still the using block)

If objects are not being freed, either you have plenty of memory left and there is no need, or you are maintaining a reference to them in your application, and therefore the garbage collector will not free them (in case you actually use this reference you maintained)

Comment: s/out of scope/unreachable/.  Scope is actually only relevant for (uncaptured) local variables of value type.

Comment: Abouth the opened files that you mentioned, is the file size on disk the same amount of memory that the file has in memory (assuming it wasn't altered).

Comment: Not unless you read the whole file into memory. When you open a file the operating system can lock it in different ways (read/write, etc). Garbage collection is non-deterministic (i.e. it happens when it needs to) so if the file handle isn't explicitly released, the file could remain locked for longer. File handles are also limited, and the garbage collector doesn't know any of this which is why files should be closed, not left to the garbage collector

Answer (score 3):

Let's answer your questions one by one.

1. Yes, you make a new object whenever this statement is executed, however, it goes "out of scope" when you exit the method and it is eligible for garbage collection.
2. Well this would be the same as #1, except that you've used a string type.  A string type is immutable and you get a new object every time you make an assignment.
3. Yes the garbage collector collects the out of scope objects, unless you assign the object to a variable with a large scope such as class variable.
4. Yes.
5. The using statement only applies to objects that implement the IDisposable interface. If that is the case, by all means using is best for objects within a method's scope.  Don't put Foo o at a larger scope unless you have a good reason to do so.  It is best to limit the scope of any variable to the smallest scope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick overview:

- Once references are gone, your object will *likely* be garbage collected.
- You can only count on statistical collection that keeps your heap size normal provided all references to garbage are really gone. In other words, there is no guarantee a specific object will ever be garbage collected.

  - It follows that your finalizer will also never be guaranteed to be called. Avoid finalizers.
- Two common sources of leaks:

  - Event handlers and delegates are references. If you subscribe to an event of an object, you are referencing to it. If you have a delegate to an object's method, you are referencing it.
  - Unmanaged resources, by definition, are not automatically collected. This is what the IDisposable pattern is for.
- Finally, if you want a reference that does not prevent the object from getting collected, look into WeakReference.

One last thing: If you declare `Foo foo;` without assigning it you don't have to worry - nothing is leaked. If Foo is a reference type, nothing was created. If Foo is a value type, it is allocated on the stack and thus will automatically be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. What do you mean by the same? It will be re-executed every time the method is run.
3. Yes, the .Net garbage collector uses an algorithm that starts with any global/in-scope variables, traverses them while following any reference it finds recursively, and deletes any object in memory deemed to be unreachable. **[see here for more detail on Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)**
4. Yes, the memory from all variables declared in a method is released when the method exits as they are all unreachable. In addition, any variables that are declared but never used will be optimized out by the compiler, so in reality your `Foo` variable will never ever take up memory.
5. the `using` statement simply calls dispose on an `IDisposable` object when it exits, so this is equivalent to your second bullet point. Both will indicate that you are done with the object and tell the GC that you are ready to let go of it. Overwriting the only reference to the object will have a similar effect.

Comment: The link provided by CrazyJugglerDrummer is a really good read on GC.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector will come around and clean up anything that no longer has references to it. Unless you have unmanaged resources inside `Foo`, calling Dispose or using a using statement on it won't really help you much.

I'm fairly sure this applies, since it was still in C#. But, I took a game design course using XNA and we spent some time talking about the garbage collector for C#. Garbage collecting is expensive, since you have to check if you have any references to the object you want to collect. So, the GC tries to put this off as long as possible. So, as long as you weren't running out of physical memory when your program went to 700MB, it might just be the GC being lazy and not worrying about it yet.

But, if you just use `Foo o` outside the loop and create a `o = new Foo()` each time around, it should all work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian points out the GC can collect anything that is unreachable including objects that are still in scope and even while instance methods of those objects are still executing. consider the following code:

```
class foo
{
    static int liveFooInstances;

    public foo()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref foo.liveFooInstances);
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("entering method");
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref foo.liveFooInstances, 1, 1) == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("running GC.Collect");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("exiting method");
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in ~foo");
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref foo.liveFooInstances);
    }

}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foo aFoo = new foo();
        aFoo.TestMethod();
        //Console.WriteLine(aFoo.ToString()); // if this line is uncommented TestMethod will never return
    }
}
```

if run with a debug build, with the debugger attached, or with the specified line uncommented TestMethod will never return. But running without a debugger attached TestMethod will return.